# How to iterate over directory and sub directories and get the name of parent directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I am iterating through folders and finding the folders that has specific file extension. Based on the find result, I am getting the directory path as -

e.g.

> ./Config/SysMapping.txt
>
> ./Config/exclusion_list_old.txt

I want to simply get the name:

> Config

and remove

> ./

before

> Config

and everything after Config, i.e.

> /SysMapping.txt

Comment: Does dirname do everything for you?

Comment: Yes dirname does everything for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will extract the first path element after `./` and delete duplicates:

```
echo ./Config/SysMapping.txt | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

In bash, you can do:

```
P=./Config/SysMapping.txt
P=${P%/*}  # --> ./Config
P=${P#./}  # --> Config
echo "$P"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I was able to do what i wanted to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`dirname <path>` would remove the file at the end of your path. In your example you'd end up with `./Config`. You can then pipe this to `awk '{ gsub(/^\.\//, ""); print }'` to remove the `./`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `globstar` setting:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
files=(**/*.txt)

# if there cannot be newlines in filenames
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]%/*}" | sort -u

# if there can be newlines in filenames
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]%/*}" | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'
```

The `tr` is there just to print the dirnames nicely at the end. You can choose to process the null delimited dirnames differently, with a `while` loop for example.